# Who are clients of ZooKeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, apache-curator

Just started reading the Documentation of Zookeeper. Read that zk has servers ( followers + leader) and clients. Who actually are the clients of zk ?  The nodes of distributed system that it co-ordinates ?
 Also read that

> ZooKeeper applications run on thousands of machines, and it performs best where reads are more common than writes, at ratios of around 10:1.

Does this means that znodes are thousands in numbers ? And what kind of read and write do we want on zk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Who actually are the clients of zk ?

A client is any process that connects to the ZooKeeper ensemble using the ZooKeeper client API.  Apache ZooKeeper ships with API bindings for [Java](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Java+Binding) and [C](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#C+Binding).  More information about the Java API is available in the [JavaDocs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/api/index.html) and [examples](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/javaExample.html) and [recipes](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/recipes.html).

> > ZooKeeper applications run on thousands of machines, and it performs best where reads are more common than writes, at ratios of around 10:1.
>
> Does this means that znodes are thousands in numbers ?

The "thousands" here refers to the number of machines running ZooKeeper, not the number of znodes stored in the ZooKeeper ensemble.  A [znode](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_zkDataModel_znodes) refers to a node stored within the ZooKeeper cluster's hierarchy of data, similar to the concept of an inode in a tradtional file system.

> And what kind of read and write do we want on zk ?

Reads refer to operations that get data from znodes or set watches to be informed when changes are applied to znodes.  Writes refer to operations that create new znodes, delete existing znodes, or change data attached to znodes.

Reading through the API docs, examples and recipes should shed more light on all of this.

Comment: Thank you. What actually is the difference between a host in an ensemble, a znode and a server ?  Is  there some relationship b/w them ?

Comment: @user3150716 , ZooKeeper uses the terminology "ensemble" to refer to the cluster of "hosts" or "servers" running the server side of the ZooKeeper software.  A "znode" is a single item of data that ZooKeeper stores in its hierarchy of data.  It's conceptually somewhat similar to an "inode" in a traditional file system.  I have edited the answer to add a hyperlink to more documentation about znodes.  https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_zkDataModel_znodes